# I want to change all background: Rgb(36,36,36) to white after user press the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a light theme on my study project. I need JS code which will change all `rgb(36,36,36)` to `rgb(255,255,255)`. I tried to change only `.publication` text color, but it use only one class instead of two. And I don't know why but `querySelector('main')` doesn't work. Anyway I need to change all background

```js
let divBlock = document.getElementById("block");
divBlock.style.padding = '1px'

function showDiv() {
  divBlock.style.opacity = '1'
  divBlock.style.top = '100px'
  divBlock.style.display = 'block'
  divBlock.style.transition = "0.3s"
}

function closeDiv() {
  divBlock.style.opacity = '0'
  divBlock.style.top = '-400px'
  divBlock.style.display = 'block'
  divBlock.style.transition = "0.3s"
}
```

```css
.navline {
  position: relative;
  margin: -20px;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  width: 102%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.RegAndLogin {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
}

.RegAndLogin>button {
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px rgb(36, 36, 36);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>button:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>div {
  color: white;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.RegAndLogin>div>button {
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px rgb(36, 36, 36);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>div>button:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: white;
}

aside>ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
}

aside>ul>div {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
}

.publication {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid aliceblue 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 25%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

canvas {
  height: 120%;
  width: 110%;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: -20px;
  background: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: initial;
}

html {
  overflow-x: unset;
}


/* .Settings {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: none;
} */

#block {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -400px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 0.5px solid aliceblue;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  top: 270px;
  left: 50px;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div id="block">
    <button class="close" onclick="closeDiv()">Close</button>
    <button id="Theme" onclick="mainColor()">Change theme</button>
  </div>
  <div class="navline">
    <div class="RegAndLogin">
      <button>Register</button>
      <button>Login</button>
      <div>
        <button>Home</button>
        <button>About</button>
        <button>Contact</button>
        <button id="Settings" onclick="showDiv()">Settings</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<aside>

  <ul>
    <hr>
    <li>Genre</li>
    <button type="button"><div>Lorem</div></button>
    <li>Data</li>
  </ul>

</aside>
<main>
  <div id="public">
    <div class="publication" id="pub">
      <h2>Publication name</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates porro harum similique ab! Non ipsa consectetur voluptate et commodi harum tempore, vel praesentium officiis ratione numquam blanditiis, quidem inventore sapiente.</div>
      <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="publication" id="pub">
      <h2>Publication name</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates porro harum similique ab! Non ipsa consectetur voluptate et commodi harum tempore, vel praesentium officiis ratione numquam blanditiis, quidem inventore sapiente.</div>
      <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: You have three buttons. Which one do you mean?

Comment: setting > change theme

Comment: _“And I don't know why but querySelector('main') doesn't work.”_ - and I don’t know why you talk about stuff “not working”, that isn’t even contained in the code you have shown us. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please keep the `id` attribute's value unique. You have used `id="pub"` twice. Also if you are replacing using Javascript, you have to use loop as you will get only first occurrence of any element and that is why you have to loop through all elements with `.publication` class

Comment: My fault! The publication uses the same color parameters as the main one, apparently, if you remove the text color parameter in the publication, then everything will work. querySelector worked! I just blunted, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fast approach:
I added the function `mainColor()`, which was not present in the OP.

My approach is to add a `className` value `theme` to the `<html>` element and set the CSS style for any element which should change as a descender of the `.theme` element

```
.theme .navline {
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .RegAndLogin>button {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .RegAndLogin>div>button {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .close {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Since these are more specific (See [MDN on specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) they will override the original styles

I do this in the function `mainColor`

```
function mainColor() {
   document.documentElement.classList.add('theme')
}
```

```js
let divBlock = document.getElementById("block");
divBlock.style.padding = '1px'

function showDiv() {
  divBlock.style.opacity = '1'
  divBlock.style.top = '100px'
  divBlock.style.display = 'block'
  divBlock.style.transition = "0.3s"
}

function closeDiv() {
  divBlock.style.opacity = '0'
  divBlock.style.top = '-400px'
  divBlock.style.display = 'block'
  divBlock.style.transition = "0.3s"
}

function mainColor() {
   document.documentElement.classList.add('theme')
}
```

```css
.theme .navline {
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .RegAndLogin>button {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .RegAndLogin>div>button {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.theme .close {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navline {
  position: relative;
  margin: -20px;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  width: 102%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}



.RegAndLogin {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
}

.RegAndLogin>button {
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px rgb(36, 36, 36);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>button:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>div {
  color: white;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.RegAndLogin>div>button {
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px rgb(36, 36, 36);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.RegAndLogin>div>button:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: white;
}

aside>ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
}

aside>ul>div {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
}

.publication {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid aliceblue 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 25%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

canvas {
  height: 120%;
  width: 110%;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: -20px;
  background: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: initial;
}

html {
  overflow-x: unset;
}


/* .Settings {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: none;
} */

#block {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -400px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 0.5px solid aliceblue;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  top: 270px;
  left: 50px;
  background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid rgb(36, 36, 36);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div id="block">
    <button class="close" onclick="closeDiv()">Close</button>
    <button id="Theme" onclick="mainColor()">Change theme</button>
  </div>
  <div class="navline">
    <div class="RegAndLogin">
      <button>Register</button>
      <button>Login</button>
      <div>
        <button>Home</button>
        <button>About</button>
        <button>Contact</button>
        <button id="Settings" onclick="showDiv()">Settings</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
<aside>

  <ul>
    <hr>
    <li>Genre</li>
    <button type="button"><div>Lorem</div></button>
    <li>Data</li>
  </ul>

</aside>
<main>
  <div id="public">
    <div class="publication" id="pub">
      <h2>Publication name</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates porro harum similique ab! Non ipsa consectetur voluptate et commodi harum tempore, vel praesentium officiis ratione numquam blanditiis, quidem inventore sapiente.</div>
      <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="publication" id="pub">
      <h2>Publication name</h2>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates porro harum similique ab! Non ipsa consectetur voluptate et commodi harum tempore, vel praesentium officiis ratione numquam blanditiis, quidem inventore sapiente.</div>
      <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I would rather use "toggle" than "add" when it comes to adding `theme` in `mainFunction`, so it can be changed back to black. I would also group the buttons and `.close` together so I don't have to repeat code.

Comment: @RickardElimää I think the asker is a early learner. I don't want to overwhelm him whith to many options